# Does "location" have the same meaning as "place"?

Tags: word-choice

I wonder if "location" and "place" can be interchangeably used?

Where is the best **place** to place a piano in a house?

Where is the best **location** to place a piano in a house?

"location" seems to me that it implies bigger places such as a building, house, island.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your question focuses on the nouns *location* and *place*. It seems awkward to query for location within a small area such as a house.  Location stems from the verb to locate, "to establish oneself or one's business," which implies a larger areal context.  Someone later seeking the location of the piano approaches the question from a context more like "where in town is the piano?" whereas someone who knows *a priori* the piano can be found in the house would ask simply "where is the piano?" I will concede though that asking "in what place is the piano" goes further afield, inquiring about the name of the town.  So, I don't find the two terms to be completely interchangeable, but only on the basis of current conventions.  Perhaps the best way to state this would be "Where is the best **place** to **put** a piano in a house" (but now the discussion shifts to put *vs.* to place).

Comment: Nice explanation, it would benefit from a linked referrence to an authoritative source in support of the claims.

Comment: I would say that the difference has been established "from first principles" and is good as it is.

Comment: Merriam-Webster's second transitive sense of [*locate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/locate) is "to set or establish in a particular spot : STATION // located the clock in the exact center of the mantel." This contradicts your assertion that *locate* is not used for small areas. This answer suffers from the same problem as the other answer: a lack of supporting evidence for its claim.

Answer (score -2):

The word *location* is derived from the verb *locate* and implies some degree of searching.

"Where is it located?" is pretty much the equivalent of "Where's it found?" or "Where would I find it?"

As in -

> In California, some of the best architecture is *found* in
>   out-of-the-way places.

A *place*, as you've correctly noted, is more concrete, i.e. something that has geographic coordinates.

Let me try to confuse you even further:

Places are usually *found*, whereas locations are determined or established.

> What would be the best place for a piano in a house?

- sounds good, whilst -

> What would be the best location for a piano in a house?

- is a bit awkward.

Your initial assumption works.

*Placing* a piano somewhere means transporting it there.

*Locating* a piano means seeing, after a bit of searching, where it's already been put.

Comment: It should also be noted that *place* has various idiomatic, metaphorical and semi-metaphorical uses (e.g. 'to put someone in his place'), which *location* doesn't.

Comment: I think of placing a piano somewhere as meaning more of “depositing or positioning it there” and less about transporting it.

Comment: None of this separation of the two words is supported by their dictionary definitions. In fact, the very first sentence is incorrect. The intransitive sense of Merriam-Webster's definition of the verb [*locate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/locate) is ": to establish oneself or one's business : SETTLE // The company will *locate* north of the city." Meanwhile, the second transitive sense is "to set or establish in a particular spot : STATION // *located* the clock in the exact center of the mantel." This is not "searching," and it's exactly what you'd do with a piano …